# How to install custom SNMP extension agent on Windows 10?

Tags: c++, windows, operating-system, snmp

I have developed a custom `snmp` extension agent to work in conjunction with `Windows Snmp service`. I have implemented in `C++` using the interface provided by `snmp.h` from Microsoft and I am creating a 64 bit `dll` to be used as extension agent.

To install this dll as extension agent I have added a registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SNMP\Parameters\ExtensionAgents` as:

```
MyAgent    REG_SZ    SOFTWARE\MyAgent\CurrentVersion
```

And under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyAgent\CurrentVersion`, I have created another registry specifying the path of the dll as:

```
Pathname   REG_EXPAND_SZ    C:\Program Files\testing\MyAgent.dll
```

When I did this in the system event logs I keep getting that the `The SNMP Service is ignoring extension agent dll C:\Program Files\testing\MyAgent.dll because it is missing or misconfigured.`

The agent is a trapless agent. It exposes the `SnmpExtensionInit` and the `SnmpExtensionQuery` function from `snmp.h`. I don't know what is messed up. Do I need a 32 bit dll? All of the sources on internet are very old and refer to `Windows NT`. I need to configure it on newer operating systems like `Windows 10` and `Windows server 2016`. Any suggestions would help.

Also there are similar questions on SO for same error but all of them are related to migration of a 32 bit dll. I am starting with 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

because the SNMP process is still 32-bit the key needs to be

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6232Node\MyAgent\CurrentVersion

but I am finding the SnmpExtensionInit is not called